# Iterating whole list and updating string using ToLower - Not working

Tags: c#, list, email, .net-4.0

**Technologies using.**

1. C#
2. .NET 4.0
3. Visual Studio 2010

**Problem.**

I have a `List<User>` which contains an **Email** property. I want to lowercase all the email addresses within the list, but my implementation is not working. I'm using the following statement:

```
emails.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ToLower());
```

This didnt work at all for email addresses like **Catherine.Burke@email.co.uk**.  I built the following to test this:

```
    string email = "Catherine.Burke@email.co.uk";
    email = email.ToLower();
    Console.WriteLine("Email: " + email);

    string email2 = "Catherine.Burke@email.co.uk";
    string email3 = "Gareth.bradley@email.co.uk";

    List<string> emails = new List<string>();
    emails.Add(email2);
    emails.Add(email3);
    emails.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ToLower());
    emails.ToList().ForEach(delegate(string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ForEach deletegate : " + e);
    });

    List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
    emailAddresses.Add(new EmailAddress { FullAddress = "Catherine.Burke@email.co.uk" });
    emailAddresses.Add(new EmailAddress { FullAddress = "Gareth.bradley@email.co.uk" });
    emailAddresses.ToList().ForEach(e => e.FullAddress.ToLower());
    emailAddresses.ToList().ForEach(delegate(EmailAddress e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EmailAddress delegate: " + e.FullAddress);
    });

    foreach (EmailAddress em in emailAddresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foreach Print: " + em.FullAddress);
    }
```

Now I thought it might be the Culture and as these are names, it kept them uppercase, but when I used `ToLower()` on a singular string it worked. The above ran with the following output, as you can see the 1st line shows an email address with lowercase characters, whereas the implementation of the various List's I tried using `ForEach()` have not worked. I'm presuming my implementation of `ForEach()` is incorrect?

[image]

Comment: Use a simple `for`-loop. `List.ForEach` is a method where you get the string as argument, you can't replace the whole reference there and since strings are immutable you can't change them either.

Comment: Did you notice that in the only situation where it works you reassign the result of the ToLower call?

Comment: @TimSchmelter/ @Steve: Thanks for the speedy comments - I think i was over thinking the situation

Comment: @TimSchmelter / Steve: Create an answer so I can give you some points :D

Comment: I would put the logic in the FullAddress property and do value.ToLower() in the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Making my comment an answer as requested:</sub>

Use a simple `for`-loop. `List.ForEach` is a method where you get the `string` as argument, you can't replace the whole reference there and since strings are immutable you can't change them either. You have to reassign the `string` returned from `String.ToLower` to your variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < emails.Count; i++)
    emails[i] = emails[i].ToLower();
```

Side-note: if you are making all emails lowercase to get a case-insensitive comparison it's better to use the `String.Equals` overload with the right [`StringComparison`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string email1 = "Catherine.Burke@email.co.uk";
string email2 = "catherine.burke@email.co.uk";
if (String.Equals(email1, email2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`emails.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ToLower());` does just call `ToLower()` but does not assign the result.

What you want is:

```
var lowerEmails = emails.Select(e => e.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Comment: this won´t change the list OP already instantiated but create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
emailAddresses.ToList().ForEach(e => e.FullAddress = e.FullAdress.ToLower());
```

As weertzui altready mentions the `ForEach`-method simply calls the delegate. However the result of this action is not used in your code in any way.

However I´d strongly recommend to use a simply foreach:

```
foreach(var mail in emailadresses) mail.FullAdress = mail.FullAdress.ToLower();
```

which seems better readable to me.